# Modify Data Privacy Levels via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

How do I modify Data Privacy levels via VBA?

i.e. I have a Workbook which needs to allow refreshing on all users' computers, however I do not want them to have to click past the "Choose Privacy Level" option.

The workbook is generated via VBA, so I want to disable privacy levels for the new workbook via VBA (so when it is opened and refreshed the privacy level does not pop up?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using:

```
ThisWorkbook.Queries.FastCombine = True
```

Fast Combine sets the workbook to ignore the privacy levels for each source - and it applies to all users of the workbook.

More information available here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gilraviv/2015/11/25/use-vba-to-enable-fast-combine-in-excel-2016/

Comment: You are a lifesaver!!

Comment: this ia amazing!